# Get Content of Template Block to Use in IF Statement

Tags: django, django-templates

Currently I have a block setup for my page titles in my `base.html`. It takes a unique value from each template page, and adds the website name to the end. For example: `ABOUT US - My Site Name`. The "ABOUT US" is passed by template and " - My Site Name" appears on every page regardless.

However, I want to use the same `base.html` on my index page, but only show "My Site Name." I was hoping to use an if statement by parsing the block each template passes to look for a unique value, signifying I am on the index page.

So far my code looks like this:

```
<title>
    {% if {% block title %}{% endblock %} == "index_pg" %}
        My Site Name
    {% else %}
        {% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Site Name
    {% endif %}
</title>
```

obviously this doesn't work. Anyone ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I would use two blocks, one wrapped around the other, something like this:

```
# base.html template
<title>
  {% block title %}
    {% block inner_title %}{% endblock inner_title %} - The Stock Column
  {% endblock title %}
</title>
```

So for most of your pages, you would extend `base.html`, and do this:

```
{% block inner_title %}Page XYZ{% endblock inner_title %}
```

And then on your index page, you would also extend `base.html`, but you would then do this:

```
{% block title %}TEST{% endblock title %}
```

The resulting output from the first one would be:

```
<title>Page XYZ - The Stock Column</title>
```

And the output of the second one, from your index page, would be:

```
<title>TEST</title>
```

Comment: Just so I know whats going on (it worked, but admitted flew over my head). `{% block inner_title %}` overrides `{% block title %}`?

Comment: Oh no problem! Actually it's the opposite - the `title` block overrides the `inner_title` block; so that means that when any particular template calls the `title` block, the `inner_title` block is basically ignored. It's almost like saying "Django, just let me replace the entire contents of the `title` block with *this*". And with this particular arrangement, the `inner_title` is part of the contents of that `title` block - and so it would be ignored/replaced with whatever you put inside of the `title` block.